# Android Geofence: Asking for exit action when already outside

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence

What happens if an Android Geofence is created with an exit transition action, e.g.:

```
Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT
```

When the device is outside the geofence? Is the geofence omitted, or does it trigger an immediate exit action?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want to know if you are going to be notified if you leave a Fence with this action? If this is the question, the answer is yes. You can specify to be notified when you enter or exits a Fence independently.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean this: When a Geofence is created, you can configure whether Android should notify you right away depending on where the phone is located when the geofence is created:

it's a method on the GeofencingRequest called **setInitialTrigger**. For example, you could configure it with **GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER**, in which case your listener would be triggered right away if you are inside the geofence when you create it.

See more here:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingRequest.Builder.html#setInitialTrigger(int)

Comment: Initial exit transitions are unreliable based on my testing. They work the first ever time only.

Answer (score 0):

Geofence will provide an exit callback every-time, ONLY when the device moves from a location inside the geofence to outside it.

If you are already outside the fence, and you haven't made the transition from inside to outside, you will not get any callback.